# Log in to site programmatically and redirect browser to signed in state

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-post, fiddler

I want to sign in to a site when a link is clicked and then redirect the browser there with a signed in session. Im having some troubles and here is what Ive tried:

First I get the session cookies from the login site:

```
CookieContainer cookies= new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://someuri.com");
myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
myHttpWebResponse.Close();
```

Then I post to the sign in page to get signed in:

```
HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://signInURL.com");
getRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PostParameterStringWithSignInInfo);
getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
newStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
```

Then I figured I need to set the cookies to the client:

```
CookieCollection cooki = getRequest.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://someUri.com"));
for(int i = 0; i < cooki.Count; i++)
{
    Cookie c = cooki[i];
    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(c.Name, c.Value));
}
```

And then redirect to where you end up being signed in:

```
Response.Redirect("http://URLwhenBeingSignedIn.com");
```

This doesnt work. When redirected Im still logged out.

Tried to do this with Fiddler and succeeded to sign in and get redirected:

Get the session cookies:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: someuri.com
```

Post to the sign in page to get signed in:

```
POST /signIn HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://someuri.com
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.7,tr;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 90
DNT: 1
Host: signInURL.com
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=fromBefore; Cookie2=fromBefore

PostParameterStringWithSignInInfo
```

Perhaps there's an easier way than the one I thought of now that you can see the fiddler requests that works, if so I'm happy to see it.

Comment: Your question is missing important information. Where is *your* code running? What browser are you using? Inside the browser, Site A cannot set a cookie that will be sent to unrelated Site B, so if you're hoping to do that, you're out of luck.

Comment: I dont understand why I cant repeat the requests Ive done in Fiddler to sign in the browser with my web app? Site A gets the cookies that Site B requires to process the post data...its just repeating what the site does when you sign in manually.

Comment: Where is your code running? What browser are you using? As I said, a website can't set a cookie for a different website-- is that what you were hoping to do?

Comment: It runs locally the browser is chrome. If you have a look at the last two requests I wrote above, thats what I want to do. Just get the cookies to use its data in the post request. (Cookie: JSESSIONID=fromBefore; Cookie2=fromBefore) - those cookies are set by the response I get from GET / HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: someuri.com. It works in fiddler so its not a question weather it works or not.

Comment: If you are signing in to a site with https , i am afraid it will not work. As due to security reason you do not get all the cookie information unlike when you sign in from a webbrowser. I have faced similar issue in past so this is my suggestion which might not be accurate.

Comment: @mdc did you find a solution for this approach? if so, please help with this. I am trying to do the same.

Comment: @TiagoHuezo No, sorry. Never found the problem and didn't work on it more after that. Post the answer here if you find out what it is.